# Why can't a CPU thread take the address of a CUDA __device__ function?

Tags: cuda

To pass a device function pointer, we have to

```
typedef int (*fp_t)(int);

__device__ int dev_fn(int)
{
    // do something
}

__device__ fp_t dev_fp = dev_fn; // [1]

void host_fn()
{
    fp_t fp;
    cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&fp, (void const*)&dev_fp, sizeof(fp));
    // now you can pass fp to cuda functions
}
```

which is quite convoluted as we have to get the address of `dev_fn` and store it to another symbol as at [1] above.

Why doesn't device function make itself a symbol so that we can use `cudaGetSymbolAddress` at host side to get the address of `dev_fn` directly instead of through an intermediate symbol `dev_fp`?

Comment: `dev_fn` doesn't have an address that the host compiler or CPU can reason about in the same way as normal functions.

Comment: @JaredHoberock I can print out the address of `dev_fn` on CPU, what does that mean? a garbage value?

Comment: It's a function pointer that the GPU can reason about. If you attempt to call it from the CPU, your program will crash.

Comment: @JaredHoberock that's why I tried to use `cudaGetSymbolAddress` and pass it to GPU, but it didn't work.

Comment: As far as C and C++ are concerned, function names are symbols. CUDA however doesn't define what it means by "symbol", so maybe their definition is different. IOW, it's either a bug or a design choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason, CUDA made the design choice of allowing CPU threads to take the address of `__device__` variables, probably because there had to be a way to copy data into and out of them. It would make no sense to attempt to copy data to the address of a `__device__` function.

It's possible something similar could be engineered to take the address of `__device__` functions, but it's unlikely the solution could be made to work well with `__host__ __device__` functions. There's no single address that makes sense for `__host__ __device__` functions.

Comment: I didn't think of `__host__ __device__` functions, that may explain why the CUDA team made the decision.